# Argument without a $ sign

Tags: php, arguments

I have just started learning php and came across this code

```
public function __construct(Enviroment $enviroment) {

//blah blah 

}
```

In this code whats the **Environment** before the environment variable. Searched on google a lot but didnt find anything. Can anyone help me with this and give some link which i can refer and understand more about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 5):

This is called Type Hinting in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

The constructor expects `$environment` to be an `Object` of class Environment.

Answer (score 2):

the Enviroment setted as your code states that the required parameter to launch the __construct is a variable of a determinate Class, you can find more info on php.net -> http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0):

$enviroment is an object and Enviroment is a methode of this objects.

It allows him to accept the argument that an object after this method.